# Meteor not running mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I run my meteor server, but is failing in the end because mongo.
Is one rocketchat and this ran in my other pc, i just copy it for my new one and i gotting this problem.

```
• Running dsv in 21 packages
@rocket.chat/cas-validate:build: cache hit, replaying output 0962d02fad6bf0a6
@rocket.chat/favicon:build: cache hit, replaying output 9d489904c7e399d8
@rocket.chat/agenda:build: cache hit, replaying output 54151d96baae71c8
@rocket.chat/ui-composer:build: cache hit, replaying output da8a2744554f494d
@rocket.chat/livechat:build: cache hit, replaying output eba6b26011eb51ba
@rocket.chat/livechat:build: Child
@rocket.chat/livechat:build:     
@rocket.chat/livechat:build:    
 
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).

@rocket.chat/presence:build: cache hit, replaying output 4c72cb2f38e68bbc
@rocket.chat/ui-theming:build: cache hit, replaying output 0ee0f1041a009c65
@rocket.chat/web-ui-registration:build: cache hit, replaying output 6489e4cd9fd06949
@rocket.chat/ui-video-conf:build: cache hit, replaying output 2fc1072730b51add
@rocket.chat/ui-client:build: cache hit, replaying output a101bb5440723b91
@rocket.chat/gazzodown:build: cache hit, replaying output 2d9d6359e45f5291
@rocket.chat/fuselage-ui-kit:build: cache hit, replaying output 399ee565c44dc57f
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: cache bypass, force executing 334f457d0cfeb8ed
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: 
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: > @rocket.chat/meteor@5.5.0-develop dev /home/hugo/Rocket.Chat/apps/meteor
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: > meteor --exclude-archs "web.browser.legacy, web.cordova"
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: 
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: [[[[[ ~/Rocket.Chat/apps/meteor ]]]]]
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: 
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: => Started proxy.
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: => Meteor 2.10.0 is available. Check the changelog
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html and update this project with 'meteor
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: update'.
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
@rocket.chat/meteor:dsv: Can't start Mongo server.
```

Comment: Meteor should not run on your server, you should build with `meteor build` and run the node app on your server. How did you install the build tarball and mongo on your server?

Comment: Thanks, its a versions conflit between the meteor runner and mongod container.

Comment: Hey, Can you help me with this... I am also facing the same error